# Como buscar registros que se encaixem em qualquer categoria de uma lista, mesmo que o nome da categoria só coincida parcialmente?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu tenho esta instrução:

```
$nova   = (explode('/', implode('/', $_GET['tipo'])));
```

Que resulta neste array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CONJUNTO
    [1] => SALA
    [2] => LOJA
)
```

Quando eu faço esta consulta no meu banco de dados ...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE CATEGORIA IN ('".implode("','", $nova)."')";
```

... ele me retorna somente os resultados de `LOJA` e eu sei porque, pelo motivo que `CONJUNTO` e `SALA` estão dentro de uma só string, assim: `CONJUNTO/SALA`, então como ele busca pela instrução **exata** não me traz estes resultados.

Uma das instruções SQL permite que ele me traga também resultados contendo estes índices por comparação aproximada que para este caso vai ser perfeito.

Me ajudem a aplicar esta instrução a essa `$sql`??

Comment: Um passo é definir este "aproximado".

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que você está querendo o chamado "Pattern Matching".
Tente usar a cláusula LIKE do SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE CATEGORIA LIKE ('%CONJUNTO%')";
```

http://blog.caosdevelopers.com/leonardo/2010/05/consulta-mysql-like/

Documentação:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html